# Use UICollectionView with transparent navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar

I am building an iOS application and have done all the layouts using storyboards and auto layout.

I have a view controller with the view hierarchy as follows.

[image]

And for the collection view I have added constraints as follows,

[image]

For this whole view I have put a background image, as shown in the screen shot.

[image]

What I want to achieve is to make the navigation bar transparent and get the collection view to scroll only up to the point where the navigation bar is met.

I have tried setting the contentInset of the collection view as follows,

```
_collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, 0, 0);
```

But there is no change. 
I have also tried embedding the collection view inside another UIView, but still the collection view goes out of the bounds of that view as well.

With what I have right now the collection view scrolls as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

Is there any way to resolve this? It'll be a great help if someone can help out.

Comment: Can you show the expected design?

Comment: Have you found any solution to that problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't scroll up over the navigation bar. So, you need customize the bar like navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:YES];
```

It works for me.

Comment: Yea making the navigation bar transparent is not the problem. The problem is to make the collection view scroll only up to the navigation bar, and not beyond. is there a way to do that?

Comment: Try resizing de frame of the contentView instead of te insents

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set +44 in the y origin of your collection view:

```
self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(self.collectionView.frame.origin.x, 44, self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.collectionView.frame.size.height);
```

and leave the contentInset with y=0:

```
collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```